# How to copy & paste from a cell in Libre Office Calc

Tags: copy-paste, libreoffice-calc

I have an Excel format spreadsheet that was sent to me by a colleague. It's a list of test usernames for an app we're building.

When I try to copy one of the usernames or passwords from the cell in LibreOffice Calc 3.4.3, and either paste into the login box of our application - or just into a notepad, it doesn't always copy. Sometimes randomly clicking on the cell a few times does the trick, sometimes attempting to paste a few times will allow allow it to copy.

There's no formulas, no formatting - it's just a basic cell with some text in it.

This is driving me crazy - any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be right-clicking in the cell to bring up a context menu. With spell checking turned on and if the cell contains a word not in the dictionary, when you right click on the word to bring up a context menu, you get a spell check context menu instead. Try right clicking in the cell but not on the word, or turn off spell checking.

Comment: Thanks - but I wasn't right clicking - I was using ctrl-c & ctrl-v. Weirdly though turning off spell checking seems to have fixed it for ctrl-c / ctrl-v too! **edit** I'd vote up, but I don't have enough reputation on this site.

Comment: @Hippyjim I've +1 for you!